# Advice sought on deriving optimal configuration parameters for C# app - possibly a learning problem

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, console-application

Here is my situation:

My company has a little C# console app, with a config file. In that config file is approximately 20 calibration parameters for our equipment (a vibration measurement device). We go through a manual process where we use in-house knowledge to manually tweak the calibration parameters, do a test run, tweak again, and iterate until we get correct calibration parameters. It's effectively a human loop.

Now this is a bit inefficient and time consuming, and I can't help thinking that this process is something we can automate. However, I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this properly and what techniques are available to me to try and solve this issue.

I can for example, just write some code that loops through every parameter combination, and brute force finds the most accurate parameter set, however this is ugly and we quickly get to billions of iterations.

It seems to me this is some kind of learning or neural network problem, and I could possibly refactor the code to somehow use this. However I'm not sure if this is actually the case.

Based on the above, what is an appropriate technique to use here? What is available in C# to facilitate this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you find ot if combinations of parameters are good in automate manner?

Comment: Well yeah, that's what I'm trying to ask advice about.

Comment: Than I recommend genetic algorithms. From description seems the problem is well suited to them.

Comment: Ok, thankyou I will think about that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem cries for a genetic algorithm. You could for example try [GeneticSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp) for a fast and easy way to achieve what you want.
Every parameter that has to be optimized will be a seperate [FloatingPointChoromosome](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/blob/master/src/GeneticSharp.Domain/Chromosomes/FloatingPointChromosome.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a version of 'hyper-parameter tuning'. You could use for instance the [hyperopt library](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) to help you come to the optimal solution faster. You can see an example [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-optimization-in-python-part-2-hyperopt-5f661db91324).